# What is the difference between the camera and image picker plugins?

Tags: flutter

I’m pretty new in flutter. So bear with me. I’m not sure the difference between plugin “camera” and “image picker”. 
I was able to capture video and image by using “image picker”. From my perspective,”image picker” is more straightforward and easy to implement but on the internet, seems like “camera” plugin is more popular. 
Then I want to ask, when it comes to taking video and picture, especially video. Is there any pros and cons? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The two plugins differ in functionality and most importantly in purpose:

- [`camera`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera) allows you to embed the camera feed into your own application as a widget, i.e. have control over it as well.
- The [`image_picker` plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) will launch a different application (a camera *or* gallery application) and return a `File` (an image or video file selected by the user in the other application) to your own application.

If you want to ***implement*** (and customize) the camera for you own purposes, you will have to use **`camera`**, but if you only want to ***retrieve*** imagery or video from the user, **`image_picker`** will be your choice.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. So if I use “camera”, I have to create button that starts capturing video myself right?

Comment: @TwoSan Yes, exactly. You can have a look at the [usage example code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/example/lib/main.dart), which shows how much you will need to handle yourself.

Comment: Do you know if there is some form of option to change things like brightness and shutter speed for any of those? The image_picker is very restricted in functionality and the camera plugin seems to only give access to the lens itself and does not provide and software.

Comment: Thanks! Concise statement of a very useful fact!